# ImageView Glitching AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, android-arrayadapter

Im pulling images from the server with asyncTask and drawing them on imageViews. The problem is that Images sometimes get "shuffled" and it takes them couple of seconds to deploy proper image. And it can get laggy too. Is there any easier way to do that? Am I doing something wrong?

```
 class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(RecipeActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting to server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                //JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                //JSONArray array = jsono.getJSONArray("recepies");
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Recepies rec = new Recepies();

                    rec.setName(object.getString("name"));

                    rec.setPciture(object.getString("picture"));

                    receptis.add(rec);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

and this is the MainActivity:

```
ArrayList<Recepies> recepies;
String nameRecepie, ingredients, priprema, picture;
Toolbar toolbar;

RecipesAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipes_activity);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("Dog recepies");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    receptis = new ArrayList<Recepti>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("url");

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new RecipesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, receptis);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter); //onclick listener ->
```

and my Adapter class

```
public class RecipesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Recepti> {
ArrayList<Recepti> receptisList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public RecipesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Recepti> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    receptisList = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(receptisList.get(position).getSlika());
    holder.tvName.setText(receptisList.get(position).getNaziv());
    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvName;
    public ImageView imageview;

}

protected class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You question depends on many things, first : image size/resolution second: bitmap storage capacity in Android. If you image is too big in resolution it will fillup bitmap native heap and device will work harder to free up space from bitmap heap, thats where lags comes from

Comment: There is a very good article written on the exact [topic by Google Engineer](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) also, use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or other Image Loading libs, it will do most headache work for you